# How to put variable in url with a object orientated retrofit 2 API call

Tags: android, api

Sorry if the question title is vague I was unsure of how to word it correctly.

I am trying to do a get API call which needs to have a variable in it's name.

The call is written like this in the docs

payment-request/{payment_request_id}

The way my code deals with API calls is that I have a class which holds all the address's so for this code it looks like this

```
public static final String ADD_PAYMENT_REQUEST_ID = "/api/v0/payment-request/";
```

Then another class that does the API call which looks like this

```
@GET(Request.ADD_PAYMENT_REQUEST_ID)
    void getPaymentRequest(Callback<SinglePaymentRequest> callback);
```

Then when I do the call it looks like this

```
RestClient.getInstance().getApiService().getPaymentRequest(new Callback<SinglePaymentRequest>() {

        @Override
        public void success(SinglePaymentRequest singlePaymentRequest, Response response) {

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

        }
    });
```

My problem is how do I add the extra variable onto the end of the url, thanks so much for any help

Comment: For example, the way to add an user id in the url is: @GET("/url/{id}") void getUser(@Path("id") String id, Callback<MyUser> callback);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want anything that add to the URL..it looks like below

```
public static final String ADD_PAYMENT_REQUEST_ID = "/api/v0/payment-request/{your key}";

 @GET(Request.ADD_PAYMENT_REQUEST_ID)
    void getPaymentRequest(@Path("your key") String yourstring,Callback<SinglePaymentRequest> callback);
```

Comment: I am trying this but it is underlining the @Path and not recognising it, it says cannot resolve symbol Path

Comment: Okay wait, I just pressed @and chose path from the dropdown and it worked, just going to check this works and you will get your tick, thanks os much for the help

Answer (score 2):

In retrofit 2.0 you can use like this

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/login")
Call<Model> getUserLogin(@Field("userId") String user, @Field("password") String password);
```